# Page Does Not Extend to Bottom Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, footer

My Wordpress Page footer floats in the center of the page and I wish it would reach the bottom of the browser window despite the size of the window. (See screenshot)

Click link for screen shot as I don't have permission :(

http://imgur.com/IRR0aBp

I'd post code but the style.css editor portion in Wordpress is way over the 30K character limit.

Any help or direction would be great. Thank you.

EDIT:

Not sure if this code is useful but this is from the footer.php file in Wordpress

```
    * 8.0 Footer
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

#supplementary {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.site-footer,
.site-info,
.site-info a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.site-footer {
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.footer-sidebar {
    padding-top: 48px;
}

.site-info {
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

#supplementary + .site-info {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.site-info a:hover {
    color: #41a62a;
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code please? A simple css change could solve the problem or not, but we need more info

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is you don't have enough content to push the footer to the bottom. Assuming you don't need to worry about old browser support try using flexbox.

http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

If you do need older browsers bootstrap has an example of a sticky footer. It relys on `position: absolute` and you'd need to know the height of your footer to get it perfect.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: No need to care for older browsers so the first option seems like it would be a fix, but how do I edit Wordpress HTML =/

Not sure but I think I only have access to the Style sheet, so I don't know how I could edit the HTML.  

Thanks for the help, wordpress noob here.

Comment: If you have access to the editor section of your site you have to modify the css for `style.css` which is your theme's css. Showing how would require a link to your site or a fiddle.

Comment: I've updated my OG post to show the footer portion of the style.css

Comment: Honestly you need to go start another question on how to modify a wordpress theme and provide specifics about your theme + categorize it as such.